# how can we release a private managed package without partner license

Tags: managed-package

We have created a managed package and we are in the process of releasing our beta package. Please help me understand, if we can release this package without partner license? If yes, then can we update the package and then send the new link for installation? Right now for beta, we are uninstalling and reinstalling again, as and when we make changes to the app. Please let me know if there is any way to avoid it.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BETA packages have limitation that it cannot be upgraded .You will have to uninstall and install .To gain the functionality of upgrade you will need to make it "Released Managed" .Atleast one version of Release Managed is needed .

One word of caution is be very careful with limitations once you make a package released .Some of the things are irreversible .

A partner program subscription is needed and strongly advisable if you want to publish app on the appexchange. If you are getting any monetary benefit out of your app you should work with ISV team  to ensure compliance but technically there is nothing stopping you in distributing your private managed package link

Comment: Thank you @mohith. But does it need partner license?

Comment: No .Let me add that to answer as well

Comment: Thank you. So I can release my app and then update it and send the new link to admins right?

Comment: yes you can do it